# CSS text-align does not work

Tags: html, css

I tried to use the text-align in CSS but it does not work.
here is the CSS and I also had all the body set to center, does that have to do with something?
Here is my CSS:

```css
#Swell {
 text-align: left;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```html
<a id="Swell" href="https://www.swell.com">Use Swell Bottles<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/f9/93/95/f99395b48463ee8d3bfa16f32df51c98.jpg" height="50"></a>
```

Also my CSS body text-align:

```css
body {
font-family: sans-serif;
text-align: center; 
background-color: rgb(128, 212, 255);
}
```

Dose the text-align: center have to do with the error and if that is true then how do I overwrite/fix this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An anchor element `<a>` is an inline element per default. Meaning it has no width or height on its own but rather is exactly as big as its content.

The text-align property does work in your example. It's just that the text is aligned regarding it's container. Which in this case is exactly as big as it's content. Therefore you would not see any difference.

Try to set the display property of the anchor element to block and see what happens.

```css
a{
display:block;
text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<a>Blocking beautiful</a>
```

Edit: More in line with your example:

```css
body{
text-align:center;
}

a{
display:block;
text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<body>
<a>Still beautiful</a>
<span>centered</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Please consider marking the answer if it helped you @klaartje

Comment: Sorry I meant @Stay Calm and love school buse

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div id="parentdiv">
    <a id="Swell" href="https://www.swell.com">Use Swell Bottles<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/f9/93/95/f99395b48463ee8d3bfa16f32df51c98.jpg" height="50"></a>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
font-family: sans-serif;
text-align: center; 
background-color: rgb(128, 212, 255);
}

#parentdiv {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Example

```html
<html>
<style>
body {
font-family: sans-serif;
text-align: center; 
background-color: rgb(128, 212, 255);
}
    
#parentdiv {
text-align: left;
}
</style>
<div id="parentdiv">
<a id="Swell" href="https://www.swell.com">Use Swell Bottles<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/f9/93/95/f99395b48463ee8d3bfa16f32df51c98.jpg" height="50"></a>
</div> 
</html>
```