# span tag text-align not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a line for price and I want the text-align like the first one on the left, second one on the center and the third one will be on right.

Normally the `text-align` works but I can't keep all three of them in them in the same line. Should I use something different? or there's a solution for this!?

First I tried like this:

```css
.price span {
  display: inline;
  /* also tried with block and inline-block */
}

.previous-price {
  text-align: left;
}

.present-price {
  text-align: center;
}

.discount-price {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p class="price">
  <span class="previous-price"><s>Tk. 350000</s></span>
   <span class="present-price">Tk. 227500</span>
   <span class="discount-price">(35% OFF)</span>
  </p>
```

Comment: You have syntax errors in your HTML

Comment: HTML `<span>`'s are `display: inline;` by default, so you don't need to set it manually.

Comment: correcting it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer for [CSS text-align does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357072/css-text-align-does-not-work/44357245#44357245)

```css
    .previous-price {
        float: left;
    }
    .present-price {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .discount-price {
        float:right;
    }
```

```html
    <p class="price">
        <span class="previous-price"><s>Tk. 350000</s></span>
        <span class="discount-price">(35% OFF)</span>
        <div class="present-price">Tk. 227500</div>
        
    </p>
```

Plus you should really try to write correct html. `<span class="present-price">Tk. 227500</p>` is certainly invalid. Just because most browsers give you a lot of leeway, you should try nevertheless to write correct code.

Answer (score 2):

`<span>` is an inline element and so it inherits the width of it's content. `<p>` is a block element so it's width is always the size of it's parent container. For this reason text-align: center will only align the `<span>` elements grouped into the center of `<p>`.

If the desired outcome is to have one all the way to the left, one item in the center, and one item right,

1. You can use the flex solution above, which will push everything to the corners.
2. You can set the display to inline-block and set the width percentages in your css. Additionally, once set to inline-block with a set width, you can text-align center within that.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to make the `.price` element a flex-container with the following settings:

```css
.price {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<p class="price">
  <span class="previous-price"><s>Tk. 350000</s></span>
  <span class="present-price">Tk. 227500</span>
  <span class="discount-price">(35% OFF)</span>
</p>
```

(BTW: You closed your `<span>` tags with closing `</p>` tags - I changed that in my fiddle)

Comment: `display:flex` is still not supported by all modern browsers. https://caniuse.com/#search=flex. I think this warrants at least some mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to NOT use display:inline for .price span and give it a width either fixed (like px) or in percentage.

E.g:

```css
  .price{
    width:100%;
  }
  .price span {
        display: inline-block; /* also tried with block and inline-block */
        width:150px;
    }
    .previous-price {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .present-price {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .discount-price {
        text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
    <p class="price">
        <span class="previous-price"><s>Tk. 350000</s></span>
        <span class="present-price">Tk. 227500</span>
        <span class="discount-price">(35% OFF)</span>
    </p>
```